# Python: cannot find reference to class when using import

Tags: python-3.x, class, import

I am new to python. I am using the anaconda prompt to run my code. I am trying to import a class from another module but I keep getting errors such as `cannot find reference to the class`.


P.S please don't negative mark this, or else I will lose the privilege of asking questions

I have already provided an `__init__` function.

The module itself runs just fine.

I have used `from parser import Parser`

I have used `from parser import *` statement as well

## My Parser class

```
class Parser(object):
     def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens
        self.token_index = 0
```

## My main class

`from parser import Parser`

I expected it to normally import the class, but it is unable to.

I keep getting the `cannot import name 'Parser' from 'parser' (unknown location)` when I use from parser import Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parser` is also the name of a [Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html?highlight=parser#module-parser) in the standard library.
It's likely there is a name conflict, and that Python is importing the module from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the module name to mparser and it works!